# MySQL allows multiple next-key locks on same record

Tags: mysql

Is MySQL allows multiple next-key locks on same record/range from multiple sessions? As following example shows, the *same* delete statement won't block each other.

My understanding is MySQL support MVCC, which means it has snapshot for each sessions below. Am I right?

MySQL: 5.7

Isolation level: Repeatable Read

Database: innodb

```
CREATE TABLE `game_summaries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_game_summaries_on_game_id` (`game_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

session 1

```
start transaction;
delete from game_summaries where game_id = 2;
```

session 2

```
start transaction;
delete from game_summaries where game_id = 2;
```

run `show engine innodb status \G` to get all locks

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 2849
Purge done for trx's n:o < 2841 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:

---TRANSACTION 2848, ACTIVE 8 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3, OS thread handle 139644825081600, query id 232 172.18.0.1 root starting
show engine innodb status
TABLE LOCK table `test`.`game_summaries` trx id 2848 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 27 page no 4 n bits 72 index index_game_summaries_on_game_id of table `test`.`game_summaries` trx id 2848 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

---TRANSACTION 2847, ACTIVE 18 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 139644825351936, query id 229 172.18.0.1 root
TABLE LOCK table `test`.`game_summaries` trx id 2847 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 27 page no 4 n bits 72 index index_game_summaries_on_game_id of table `test`.`game_summaries` trx id 2847 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html, the gap lock is allowed to be hold on a gap by different transactions, even you saw `lock_mode X` there.

`It is also worth noting here that conflicting locks can be held on a gap by different transactions. For example, transaction A can hold a shared gap lock (gap S-lock) on a gap while transaction B holds an exclusive gap lock (gap X-lock) on the same gap. The reason conflicting gap locks are allowed is that if a record is purged from an index, the gap locks held on the record by different transactions must be merged.`